# Does Internet Explorer have certain JS you can’t use?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a loan repayment calculator that works fine in all other browsers, but not running in IE11.

I have looked if IE11 has certain JS you can’t use and changed some of my let’s to var, but no luck.

```
<script>
    function loanRepay(){
       //Present Value 
        var pv = (parseFloat((document.getElementById("AB").value).replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g,''), 10));
        //Interest Rate (Compounded Monthly)
        var r = ((parseFloat((document.getElementById("IR").value).replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g,''), 10)) / 100) / 12;
        //Number of Compounds in a Period - Compounded monthly 
        var n = (parseFloat((document.getElementById("TL").value).replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g,''), 10));
    //Payments per Month
    var pay = pv * (r / (1 - (1 + r)**-n));
    document.getElementById("pay").innerHTML = "$" + pay.toFixed(2);
    //Interest Paid
    var interest = (pay * n) - pv;
    document.getElementById("interest").innerHTML = "Interest Paid $" + interest.toFixed(2);
    //Total Payment
    var total = interest + pv;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Amount $" + total.toFixed(2);
        //if form isn't filled out correctly
    if (isNaN(total))
    { alert('Please fill all fields with numerical values before pressing calculate.');} else{};
    }
</script>
```

IE isn’t throwing any errors, it just isn’t running. I am still learning JS and I think it is pretty simple JS, so I am not sure why it isn’t running.

Comment: don't use IE as it isn't a browser [source](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/)

Comment: What are your regexes seeking to achieve? If it's trying to remove symbols, you'll find that there are a LOT more symbols than the ones you've listed there. Consider creating a whitelist, not a blacklist. Or, if it is to be numeric, maybe just use `\D`.

Comment: For IE you need `Math.pow(1 + r, -n)` instead. (for me IE is throwing a syntax error pointing to `(1 + r)**-n`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exponentiation operator(`**`) is an ES2016+ feature and [it is not supported in IE 11](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-exponentiation_(**)_operator). Change this line to:

```
var pay = pv * (r / (1 - Math.pow(1 + r, -n)));
```

You can set up [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and its presets in your project to target specific browsers. If it is a small project or it gets too complicated, you can just paste your code in [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrADZIIZQEoFMAHTATwAoBKAbwChQ6B6egBQCc8BnPKOYANUzQQ8wWnVAA3TC2AFxwALzBSRFpwBiGTHFKkAJkhgQAtlzgA6AOZ44AUTR4T3AELEAkrtIAiAIJPP5M0lBPAC2AjRMGDxSegBtADIAHXpExIBiABoAagoAEgA_AFIAck8ALgAqAH4AHgA-SgBfAF16Cwzi4vIM4ABGAAZycgBuUTFgRlduPDZ2HhwtYVIAYSQjAiRoXTxdYABZFDgACzRicjGxSWlpRR0VdU1tPQNjU0trOwdTF3cvVxx_IEBEJQoQIlEYglkqlMjlyAUSuVqvUmq12p1un1BuQJljBrjegAmUbjECMAByxgARjNgEgwMBVutNlBdOxgAhUJhgEwZshdgBaRlrDZbHbAIyHE7EESk4BXYCoW73PAaLBPfSGRzmKy2ezan4eTwAFQAMoCgiCzGFwdE4kkUulsnkiqVKrUGi02h0uj0BkMSaBGEwSNr2QRaQduEcLgqiDLFLJgBUlNJ6EpesAhaRM1lgCxyBUKgKoAGLprXtx3nqvs43Eb44DOVAZgAJY17U0KYCeXKeYB5-NmOBINQIAAeO1IhJGF0m01mPBDCF0sakHIXHB4ypIycVOKFskDIAr2urnwN9a8nLgMy3TagLZY7c73c8U1vi55mBXwD7A43T8t2HUcJynGdjwmehjSQOABG_YhtTXaQRzgtBuxvO85gAo9yxeM9dQvb4r08VCBAfJ8Xy7RQTVg-DvElaAeH_PMyLQECx0nDwIIuBh6AQBkwCQFgjA5dgoGKHgwAQNB7F2TYeBgYS2HgU4LgEpQEHYclMHJUg2KGC5KGAAQZm0YomHsTBOHAGT0IEdDpLwNA2WAAB3BBjkVV4WAQGB4MtDhgBpIS2BkWZ2E5CxgH8tBDAiW8zC6YZGmAZzOCaSDGiAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.2&externalPlugins=) to get the transpiled code.